# Direct Hamiltonian Operator computation in polar coordinate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, commutator

Suppose a classical Hamiltonian of the form
$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{2m}(p^2_x+p^2_y)+a(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$$
We know that this change to following quantum operator

$$\hat{H}\rightarrow -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)+a(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$$
in coordinate basis. But due to rotational symmetry I want to work in polar coordinate for which I need to do the transformation from one coordinate to another.

But why I can not do the following directly from starting from Hamiltonian to be in polar coordinate. So that
$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{p^2_\rho}{2m}+\frac{p^2_\phi}{2m\rho^2}+a\rho$$
and then use the directly use operators from here:
$$\hat{P}_\rho\rightarrow -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} 
$$
$$\hat{P}_\phi\rightarrow -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} $$

as theny follow the canonical commutation rules but on doing these two both leads to different Hamiltonian operators. What's wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/501184/hamiltonian-operator-in-polar-coordinates-with-momentum-operators).  Your first Laplacian has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'll elide your question, betting you'd prefer to bypass its subtleties: I have linked one question on curvilinear coordinate quantization, and you'd find lots of answers on the subject. I think it's more important to recall the drill, employed, e.g., in spherical coordinates  for the Hydrogen atom.

That is, eschew interpretation, and convert *directly* your fine hamiltonian
$$\hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)+a(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$$to polar coordinates,
$$\hat{H}= -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left( \frac{1}{r} \partial_r ~r ~\partial_r +\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_\phi ^2\right)+a r,$$
for which you may find factorized eigenfunctions, etc.

Recall the symmetry operator commuting with your hamiltonian is $L= \partial_\phi$.

---

*NB. (Geeky)* The polar variables' measure $r~dr ~d\phi$ is not flat, so your proposed radial momentum operator is not hermitian.
You may consider the hermitian operator $\Pi= -i\hbar(\partial_r +1/2r)$, instead, inadvisably, in which case $ \Pi^2= -\hbar^2((1/r) \partial_r ~r ~\partial_r-1/4r^2)$.

Comment: Is hermitian is the only problem here?

Comment: Probably not. As I indicated,  curvilinear canonical quantization is a long/messy  problem, and should be asked about more coherently in a different question--not in a "find my error" gambit. You did not show your PB and commutator work.  I'm just bypassing to the correct answer.